# What were Roman Catholic hymns called back in the days?

Tags: history

Well, there are three sub-religions in the context of *Christianity*:

- Roman Catholicism
- Orthodoxy
- Protestantism

Before Orthodoxy and Protestantism was developed, what were Catholic hymns called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catholic hymns would have just been called "hymns" (at least by the common pepople in English-speaking countries). The clergy would have used the Latin term "hymnus" (pl. "hymnī").
Today one only needs to add the word "Catholic" if it is necessary to distinguish between hymns from the different branches.

Comment: Of course, this being The Church, Hymnis, sicut dictum esset catholica vocatur ", hymnos". Adde quod hodie est, non indiget nisi ut «catholicas» Si sic necesse est distinguere inter carmina in ramis diversis. (Thanks, Google Translate!)

Comment: There is also the somewhat overlapping noun *chorale* which seems to be combined with *Gregorianic* and *Lutheran*.

Comment: @guidot A lot of hymns are chorales, but 'chorale' refers to the musical form and is more typical of Protestantism.